# Extract data in web page

Tags: javascript, python, json, pandas, web-scraping

Trying to extract the table from this page "https://www.hkex.com.hk/Mutual-Market/Stock-Connect/Statistics/Historical-Monthly?sc_lang=en#select1=0&select2=0".

By inspect/network function of chorme, the data request link seem is "https://www.hkex.com.hk/eng/csm/MonthlyStat/data_tab_monthly_202302e.js".

I tried to use belowing code to extract the data but seem not work. Should I use another method?

My codes:

```
import pandas as pd

url='https://www.hkex.com.hk/eng/csm/MonthlyStat/data_tab_monthly_202302e.js'

import urllib.request, json 
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as r:
    data = json.loads(r.read().decode())

df = pd.DataFrame(data['tables'][0]['body'])
columns = [item['text'] for item in data['tables'][0]['header']]
row_count = max(df['row'])
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df.text.values.reshape((row_count,-1)),columns = columns)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the data from url you attached is not JSON (it starts with `tabData =` ). You can remove that part and then parse the remaining as JSON. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json

url = r'https://www.hkex.com.hk/eng/csm/MonthlyStat/data_tab_monthly_202302e.js'

response = requests.get(url)
if response.status_code != 200:
    exit(1)

text = response.text[response.text.index('=') + 1:]
data = json.loads(text)
```

Comment: But how could I convert these data to dataframe? It seems different from the JSON I met before. Can you help me convert them? I only need style 1 data from all id.